# Rails App on Google Cloud: URI must be ascii only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, request

I have a working request on localhost, which basically calls and endpoint using an address

```
  def stuart_validate_address(address)
    require 'uri'
    require 'net/http'

    ### not working with accents like Calàbria
    # url = URI("https://api.stuart.com/v2/addresses/validate?type=picking&address=#{address}")
    # url = URI.parse("https://api.stuart.com/v2/addresses/validate?type=picking&address=#{address}")
    url = URI.parse(URI.escape("https://api.stuart.com/v2/addresses/validate?type=picking&address=#{address}"))

    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
    request["authorization"] = "Bearer #{AUTH_TOKEN}"
    request.body = "{}"

    response = http.request(request)
    JSON.parse(response.read_body)
  end
```

If I use the endpoint with Postman it works, if I do the call with localhost it works. But once we are on production (gcloud) it complains about

```
URI::InvalidURIError
URI must be ascii only "https://api.stuart.com/v2/addresses/validate?type=picking&address=Córsega 494, 08025, Barcelona"
```

I know I have to parse it and escape it, but I can't figure out why I still have the same error. Also I am curious why it's working on localhost and postman, and not in Rails production environment.

Comment: Are you sure that the same code is running in both environments?

Comment: no, the data was different, in production I had the accent, I realised later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have an acute ó in your url.

If you are using Rails, you can use [string#parameterize](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/String/parameterize)

Or if plain Ruby, you use i18n gem:

```
require "i18n"
I18n.transliterate("Olá Mundo!")
 => "Ola Mundo!"
```

Comment: I was thinking that too but the issue is really that the URL is not escaped. A URL escaped string consists only of ASCII characters but can be decoded back into the original. Transliterating addresses is not a great idea as it will make it harder to get relevant results in some locales.